# what does it(source: Node | string | number) mean in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am new in typescript and trying to understand a snippet of a code. but could not understand this line of code.

```
 source: Node | string | number
```

If i am not wrong, by vertical it shows source could be string or number.but what does node do at the beginning? it's not a type of a variable. please let me know.

Comment: shows source could be `Node` , `string` or `number` . you have a type   Node defined in your code .

Answer (score 2):

The pipe (`|`) denotes a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types). It means that `source` could be either a `Node`, `string` or a `number`.

Comment: If you continue reading the section I linked to you'll see that it gives an example later on of a function that can take a union type as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

It means that `source` is a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) meaning that at runtime `source` can be either a `Node` or `string` or `number`. You will only have access to common members of the union type and you would have to use a type guard to distinguish between the types in the union:

```
var source: Node | string | number;
if(typeof source == 'string') {
    source // is string here
}
else if(typeof source == 'number') {
    source // is number here
}else {
    source // is node here
}
```